# Frame not loading with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to code a very simple game using `tkinter` in python3. It is a sequential game, played for many periods. My problem is that at the end of a period, when clicking the "next period" button, the next period is not loading. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Game(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        F=Period
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Period(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        firstOffer = 5

        labelOffer = tk.Label(self, anchor='center', text=str(firstOffer))
        labelOffer.place(anchor='center', relx=0.6, rely=0.5)  

        buttonAcc = ttk.Button(self, text='Accept', command=lambda: self.PeriodSummary(parent, controller))
        buttonAcc.place(anchor='center', relx=0.35, rely=0.5)           

    def PeriodSummary(self, parent, controller):

        buttonNextPeriod = ttk.Button(self, text='Next Period', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Period))
        buttonNextPeriod.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.75, width=200, height=80)          

app = Game()
app.wm_state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

As can be seen when the code is run, when the user clicks on "next period" nothing happens. I would like it to start a new period. I believe that I have an incorrect understanding of object orieted programming in Python. Any pointers would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the `show_frame` method is being called? That's easier to do if you remove the `lambda` and use a custom function. You can then more easily add a print function or stop with a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. I just did what you suggested (added a small `print` statement in the `show_frame` function. Indeed, the `show_frame` is not being called. But I cannot see a reason why it would not be called if the button is clicked.

Comment: Do you really need numpy in order to replicate this problem? If not, you need to condense this down into something that doesn't depend on numpy.

Comment: I suggest you read https://www.google.com/search?q=mcve&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 and reduce your code to the minimum needed to exhibit the problem.  In the future, don't write so much code without testing as you go.

Comment: Thank you @TerryJanReedy . I have followed your instructions and shortened the code, removing the code lines that are not necessary for the problem I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your comment above, putting `print(self.frames)` inside `show_frame` shows that `show_frame` *is* being called.  Since `self.frames` has only one item, `{<class '__main__.Period'>: <__main__.Period object .!frame.!period>}`, and the single Period object is already visible, `.tkraise` exposes what is already exposed and there is no visible change.  There are two ways to add dynamism.

The easy option: make one period frame, expose it, and have the `Next` button change the content.  Do this if you possibly can.

The harder option: make multiple period frames, either all at once or as needed.  Each would have a visibly different content.  Expose the first.  Then have the button expose the next.  There are two suboptions: stack identically sized gridded (or packed or placed) frames on top of eacy other and raise the one you want to see; or only grid the one you want to see, ungridded when making the switch. I would only go the multiple-frame route if you need to re-expose frames seen before.  An if you need this, use a tabbed frame widget, such as ttk.Notebook, that handles the stacking and exposing for you.  An example is a windows with multiple forms to fill, each of which may get multiple uses.  A particular example is IDLE's tabbed configuration dialog.

Comment: Thank you @TerryJanReady . I do not need to re-expose previously seen frames. I just want periods to be seen sequentially, once the button has been clicked. In my code, the `Next` button does refer to the period frame, so I do not understand why a new period is not being shown. I can just create classes as Period2, Period3, etc. But that is not elegant, there must be a simpler way.

Comment: I will ask the question in a better way in a new post.